# Microsoft365R Package, working with onedrive, uploading file to odb from local machine, run into JSON error

Tags: r, r-package, microsoft365r

Trying to move files from local drive to onedrive, running this command:

```
odb$upload_file("test.R","C:\Users\B1*****\OneDrive -******\rTestDest")
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in process_response(res, match.arg(http_status_handler), simplify) :
Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to complete operation. Message:
Empty Payload. JSON content expected.
```

Any advice?

I am trying to upload the file test.R to the destination which is a folder in my onedrive called rTestDest.